# How to fix Multiple BSOD on Windows 10 from safe mode?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, administrator, uninstall, password-recovery

Soon after installing and creating a VirtualBox, Windows froze during restart. I forced it to shut down, and have since had these [BSOD's](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x3axiiopqfs9j0r/AAAaz9fAbJFDVXtGk3Cssxdya?dl=0), as well as Page fault in non-paged area and Attempted write to read-only memory.

I have uninstalled Nvidia Geforce Experenience & graphics drivers, as the original system thread exception error ["is mostly due to old graphics drivers"](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1653141/fix-system-thread-exception-handled-error-windows.html). I now have a Secure system exception BSOD.

Comment: from your working account, copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to the desktop, create a zip of the folder, upload the zip (OneDrive) and post a link here.

Comment: Unfortunately requires my admin password.

Comment: what happens when you try to enter the admin password?

Comment: It refuses it. I'm going to try [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-reset-my-forgotten-administrators/945fcc2f-e10c-45ac-9a7f-cd4c328dd063)

Comment: That gives me "system error 5 has occurred. Access is denied"

Comment: fixed my link to a pastebin of the BSOD's

Comment: Take a external SATA controller and read the HDD

Comment: I had those because of Windows10 not liking my audio/LAN drivers. Update those to W10 compatible versions from manufacturer.

Comment: Alfabravo, still stuck with the reset admin password, so i can't update drivers from a User account in safe mode (no internet either). I've tried and failed with NTPASSWD, trying this now http://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/

Comment: this pastebin link is useless. Use a Linux Live DVD to copy and upload the files.

Comment: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x3axiiopqfs9j0r/AAAaz9fAbJFDVXtGk3Cssxdya?dl=0) of files. Turned out it wanted my microsoft password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the cash dumps, the bugchecks are caused by the driver `PSINFile.sys` which is part of Panda Security:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffff80000003, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff8035d5cc968, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: ffffd00094dc49e8, Exception Record Address
Arg4: ffffd00094dc4200, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for PSINFile.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for PSINFile.sys

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_DATE:  09/19/2012

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z77-DS3H

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffff80000003

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8035d5cc968

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd00094dc49e8

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffd00094dc4200

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!DebugPrompt+18
fffff803`5d5cc968 c3              ret

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffd00094dc49e8 -- (.exr 0xffffd00094dc49e8)
ExceptionAddress: fffff8035d5cc968 (nt!DebugPrompt+0x0000000000000018)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000002

CONTEXT:  ffffd00094dc4200 -- (.cxr 0xffffd00094dc4200)
rax=0000000000000002 rbx=fffff800bd8153c0 rcx=fffff800bd844070
rdx=ffffd00094dc001f rsi=ffffd00094dc4fb0 rdi=000000000000002f
rip=fffff8035d5cc967 rsp=ffffd00094dc4c28 rbp=ffffd00094dc4d80
 r8=ffffd00094dc4cb0  r9=0000000000000002 r10=00000000ffffffff
r11=0000000000000000 r12=ffffcf81d4d44e50 r13=0000000000000000
r14=ffffe001c282d220 r15=0000000000000003
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
nt!DebugPrompt+0x17:
fffff803`5d5cc967 cc              int     3
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: d40

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000002

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8035d6ac0b5 to fffff8035d5cc967

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!DebugPrompt
01 nt!DbgPrompt
02 FLTMGR!FltpvPrintErrors
03 FLTMGR!FltpvValidateFileNameOptions
04 FLTMGR!FltvGetFileNameInformationUnsafe
05 PSINFile
06 0x0
07 0x0
08 0x0
09 0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  PSINFile.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:av_vrf_psinfile!unknown_function

    Loaded symbol image file: PSINFile.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\PSINFile.sys
    Image name: PSINFile.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Jul 16 20:09:31 2015
```

You also had [driver verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enabled. Don't activate it again for the Panda driver.

Answer (score 0):

I reset windows 10 in Recover, which autostarts if you let the BSOD's do thier restart loop for long enough.